# CPAN install module says OK but compilation fails on that module

Tags: linux, perl, cpan

I'm trying to subclass `MIME::Parser::FileUnder` as explained [here](http://search.cpan.org/~dskoll/MIME-tools-5.504/lib/MIME/Parser/Filer.pm). So I install this module:

```
$ sudo cpan install MIME::Parser::FileUnder
[...]
Result: PASS
  DSKOLL/MIME-tools-5.504.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make test -- OK
Running make install
Manifying blib/man3/MIME::Decoder::Gzip64.3pm
Appending installation info to /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2/perllocal.pod
  DSKOLL/MIME-tools-5.504.tar.gz
  sudo /usr/bin/make install  -- OK
```

Looks like installed correctly, but

```
$ ./test_gmail.pl
Can't locate MIME/Parser/FileUnder.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at GMailMIMEParser.pm line 4.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at GMailMIMEParser.pm line 4.
Compilation failed in require at ./test_gmail.pl line 13.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./test_gmail.pl line 13.
```

If I try to install `MIME::Parser::FileUnder` again, it will strangely install it instead of telling me it's up to date like any other module.

This is my subclass `GMailMIMEParser`:

```
package GMailMIMEParser;

use strict;
use MIME::Parser::FileUnder;

our @ISA = qw(MIME::Parser::FileUnder);

my $cur = 0;

sub output_path
{
    my $class = shift;
    my $head = shift;
    print(STDERR $head);
    $cur++;
    return "./$cur";
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's a filer subclass or MIME Parser, so I think you want something like my $parser = new MIME::Parser;, then $parser->filer->output_path(xxx).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I have to subclass `MIME::Parser::FileUnder` as explained in the link to use my own `output_path()`. `GMailMIMEParser` subclasses `MIME::Parser::FileUnder`, but it won't recognize `MIME::Parser::FileUnder`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was simply doing the wrong thing. I have to subclass `MIME::Parser::Filer` and not `MIME::Parser::FileUnder`, which is itself a `MIME::Parser::Filer` subclass.

```
package GMailMIMEParser;

use strict;
use MIME::Parser::Filer;

our @ISA = qw(MIME::Parser::Filer);

my $cur = 0;

sub output_path
{
    my $class = shift;
    my $head = shift;
    print(STDERR $head);
    $cur++;
    return "./$cur";
}
```